# Attribute error when switching to Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I wanted to change an existing app to use Material Design. I left the res/values/styles.xml like this:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I defined a res/values-v21/styles.xml and put the Material Design theme in there:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Now, when I try to preview or run it on a Lollipop+ device, the design is messed up (textbox texts not showing up, among other things). It also gives this error in the design preview:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Attribute '?attr/colorAccent' not found. Are you using the right theme?
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:76)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColorStateList(BridgeTypedArray.java:372)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:750)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:667)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor115.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In my gradle file, I am using:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

with:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

and:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Did I forget to do something, or forgot to take something into account? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using ?color/accentColor in one of the layouts instead of @colors/accentColor ?

Comment: I searched all my layout files for any instance of 'accentColor' but could not find any...not sure what that is

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Removing the following line from the layout attributes solved it:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

(deleted it)

The error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using the Support library, you should prefix those attributes with `android`:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I think I am using the support library. I now have 2 styles.xml. One in directory 'values', and the other in directory 'values-v21'. The v21 one has the material design theme with the android prefix now, however I still get very similar errors. (Such as: Exception raised during rendering: Attribute '?attr/colorAccent' not found. Are you using the right theme?)

Comment: If you use Support library you'll only need a v21 style if you want to customize styles for v21. Otherwise, a single styles.xml targeting Support library is enough.

Comment: according to the documentation, if I want backward compatibility, I need two styles.xml: https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#Theme

Comment: The section is called "Define Alternative Styles", and that's exactly what I'm pointing out: if you need different styles - define two files, if the style should look the same on all range of devices - one file is enough.

Comment: Yea my alternative style works on older devices. My question is for the material design theme which doesn't work on newer devices.